# When using pykalman (Python Kalman filter), what data type does loglikelihood function take?

Tags: python, kalman-filter

I'm learning how to use the [pykalman package](https://pykalman.github.io/). I ran into an error when going through the Kalman EM example, which uses robot data. The EM example code is [here](https://github.com/pykalman/pykalman/blob/master/examples/standard/plot_em.py). The robot example comes with a description and code to generate data.

When I run this section:

```
    # Learn good values for parameters named in `em_vars` using the EM algorithm
    loglikelihoods = np.zeros(10)
    for i in range(len(loglikelihoods)):
    kf = kf.em(X=data.observations, n_iter=1)
    loglikelihoods[i] = kf.loglikelihood(data.observations)
```

I get the error below for the kf.loglikelihood(data.observations) function that says Masked Arrays are not supported. What should I be using as a parameter for kf.loglikelihood instead?

```
    C:\Users\Jenny\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pykalman-0.9.5-py3.5.egg\pykalman\standard.py in loglikelihood(self, X)
       1472         loglikelihoods = _loglikelihoods(
       1473           observation_matrices, observation_offsets, observation_covariance,
    -> 1474           predicted_state_means, predicted_state_covariances, Z
       1475         )
       1476 

    C:\Users\Jenny\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pykalman-0.9.5-py3.5.egg\pykalman\standard.py in _loglikelihoods(observation_matrices, observation_offsets, observation_covariance, predicted_state_means, predicted_state_covariances, observations)
        168                 observation[np.newaxis, :],
        169                 predicted_observation_mean[np.newaxis, :],
    --> 170                 predicted_observation_covariance[np.newaxis, :, :]
        171             )
        172     return loglikelihoods

    C:\Users\Jenny\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pykalman-0.9.5-py3.5.egg\pykalman\utils.py in log_multivariate_normal_density(X, means, covars, min_covar)
         71                                       lower=True)
         72         cv_log_det = 2 * np.sum(np.log(np.diagonal(cv_chol)))
    ---> 73         cv_sol = solve_triangular(cv_chol, (X - mu).T, lower=True).T
         74         log_prob[:, c] = - .5 * (np.sum(cv_sol ** 2, axis=1) + \
         75                                      n_dim * np.log(2 * np.pi) + cv_log_det)

    C:\Users\Jenny\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py in solve_triangular(a, b, trans, lower, unit_diagonal, overwrite_b, debug, check_finite)
        156     """
        157     a1 = _asarray_validated(a, check_finite=check_finite)
    --> 158     b1 = _asarray_validated(b, check_finite=check_finite)
        159     if len(a1.shape) != 2 or a1.shape[0] != a1.shape[1]:
        160         raise ValueError('expected square matrix')

    C:\Users\Jenny\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_util.py in _asarray_validated(a, check_finite, sparse_ok, objects_ok, mask_ok, as_inexact)
        183     if not mask_ok:
        184         if np.ma.isMaskedArray(a):
    --> 185             raise ValueError('masked arrays are not supported')
        186     toarray = np.asarray_chkfinite if check_finite else np.asarray
       187     a = toarray(a)

    ValueError: masked arrays are not supported
```

Answer (score 2):

I added the following line

```
observation=observation.filled()
```

just before line 168 of the pykalman.standard.py package file, which reads:

```
loglikelihoods[t] = log_multivariate_normal_density(
            observation[np.newaxis, :],
            predicted_observation_mean[np.newaxis, :],
            predicted_observation_covariance[np.newaxis, :, :]
)
```

Assuming you have complete observations this simple workaround will get the loglikelihood() method to work. Hopefully this won't be necessary in subsequent iterations of the package.

Answer (score -1):

Referred to the issues of pykalman on [Github](https://github.com/pykalman/pykalman/pull/53), the [solution](https://github.com/pykalman/pykalman/pull/53/commits/e6256b70bba69bcca296ee7ce0311021d53cf2c2) works for me.

What the solution mentioned in the link is basicallly modifying the code in standard.py within line 112 to 173:

```
def _loglikelihoods(observation_matrices, observation_offsets,
     for t in range(n_timesteps):
         observation = observations[t]
         if not np.any(np.ma.getmask(observation)):
+            observation_data = np.ma.getdata(observation)
             observation_matrix = _last_dims(observation_matrices, t)
             observation_offset = _last_dims(observation_offsets, t, ndims=1)
             predicted_state_mean = _last_dims(


             loglikelihoods[t] = log_multivariate_normal_density(
-                observation[np.newaxis, :],
+                observation_data[np.newaxis, :],
                 predicted_observation_mean[np.newaxis, :],
                 predicted_observation_covariance[np.newaxis, :, :]
             )
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19240836)

Comment: @StephenNewell You are right. I edited a bit. Hope this answer keep persisted.